# How to addPolygons when clicked on the a group in leaflet / shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

There is an example which shows how to use overlayGroup to control what layer to hide or display on the map when using leaflet. However, even if we set the layers to be hided, still it need to load and add the shapefiles. I have a shapefile which is pretty big, so I want it to be added only in case I click on that group. For example, consider the following example,

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("map"))

server <- function(input, output) {

outline <- quakes[chull(quakes$long, quakes$lat),]

output$map <- renderLeaflet({
leaflet(quakes) %>%
# Base groups
addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner", group = "Toner") %>%
addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", group = "Toner Lite") %>%

# Overlay groups
addCircles(~long, ~lat, ~10^mag/5, stroke = F, group = "Quakes") %>%
addPolygons(data = outline, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat,
            fill = F, weight = 2, color = "#FFFFCC", group = "Outline") %>%
hideGroup("Outline") %>%
hideGroup("Quakes") %>%
# Layers control
addLayersControl(
  baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner", "Toner Lite"),
  overlayGroups = c("Quakes", "Outline"),
  options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
 })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When running this, it will add all the layers to the "map" and then hide them to my understanding. I want to know how to move the addPolygons outside this and make it a reactive to when I click on "Outline" in the layercontrol.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage( checkboxInput('outline', "Outline"), leafletOutput("map"))

server <- function(input, output) {

  outline <- quakes[chull(quakes$long, quakes$lat),]

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leafletplot <- leaflet(quakes) %>%
      # Base groups
      addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner", group = "Toner") %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", group = "Toner Lite") %>%
      addCircles(~long, ~lat, ~10^mag/5, stroke = F, group = "Quakes")


  if(input$outline)
      leafletplot <- leafletplot %>% addPolygons(data = outline, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat,
                  fill = F, weight = 2, color = "#FFFFCC", group = "Outline")

    leafletplot %>%   hideGroup("Quakes") %>%
      # Layers control
      addLayersControl(
        baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner", "Toner Lite"),
        overlayGroups = c("Quakes"),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I should have been more specific. I do not want to use check box, I was wondering if there is a way that I could control it with checking the box in the overlayGroups.

Comment: then your solution is definitely the right (and only) way to do it.